# loop through divs and move hrefs to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to loop through `divs` take the `href` from one div and move it to the `href` of another div, and then repeat this for all the following divs.

I have it working so far as it does it for the first div but then it places that href link in all the others.

see https://jsfiddle.net/grmaw27y/5/

**html:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="image">
        <a href="#" class="">
          <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=230%C3%97230&w=230&h=230" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h2>Google</h2>
      <div class="entry">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus sit amet ipsum eget odio maximus posuere. Fusce dapibus id urna quis eleifend. Nam lacinia consequat lectus, at ultricies purus elementum non.</p>
        <p><a href="https://www.google.ie/">https://www.google.ie/</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="image">
        <a href="">
          <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=230%C3%97230&w=230&h=230" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h2>Yahoo</h2>
      <div class="entry">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
        <p><a href="https://ie.yahoo.com/">https://ie.yahoo.com/</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
$('.entry').each(function() {
  var href = $('.entry p a').attr('href');
  $('.image a').attr('href', href);
});
```

Comment: divs do not have an href attribute. You mean the only-child <a> within each div with class^="col-md-" ?

Comment: Just to make sure - for each `container` you want to take the value of the `href` that exists inside the `div.entry` and move it to the anchor that wrap the img inside `div.image` (inside the same container)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.entry').each(function(i,element) {
  var href = $(element).find('p a').attr('href');
  $(element).parent().prev().find('.image a').attr('href', href);
});
```

Working example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/grmaw27y/6/

**So what was wrong with your code?**

Your expression to find the href `var href = $('.entry p a').attr('href');` and assign href `$('.image a').attr('href', href);`, were working on class selectors. which return array of all matches. In every pass they were matching the same two elements. 
To fix this we use the `element` object in loop, you specify exactly what you want to read and write.

Comment: Thank you and thank you for the explanation, helps clear things up. Been scratching my head for a few hours trying to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use traversal functions to select elements relative to each target:

```
$('.entry').each(function() {
  var href = $('p a', this).attr('href');
  $(this).closest('.row').find('.image a').attr('href', href);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gbc22h0f/

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the `container` and find the relevant elements INSIDE each of the containers:

```js
$('.container').each(function() {
  var href = $(this).find('div.entry a').attr('href');
  $(this).find('div.image a').attr('href', href);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="image">
        <a href="#" class="">
          <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=230%C3%97230&w=230&h=230" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h2>Google</h2>
      <div class="entry">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus sit amet ipsum eget odio maximus posuere. Fusce dapibus id urna quis eleifend. Nam lacinia consequat lectus, at ultricies purus elementum non.</p>
        <p><a href="https://www.google.ie/">https://www.google.ie/</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="image">
        <a href="">
          <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=230%C3%97230&w=230&h=230" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h2>Yahoo</h2>
      <div class="entry">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
        <p><a href="https://ie.yahoo.com/">https://ie.yahoo.com/</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```